# Git hangs with 100% cpu usage (it was disk issue)

Tags: git

There are some operations that hang on one of my repositories:

- git gc: hangs with 100% usage at "Counting objects: 7409"
- when I launch gitk, it launches this command, which also hangs with 100% CPU usage:

  git log --no-color -z --pretty=raw --parents --boundary 6ca9fbc0393cbc05e6ef7d67768ff1570e3fc42e 5741492043ebbc19013baf8c1c162b32b0e37ce5 6732226ff033e0d0dcdb47aa5c69d09551252caa 16871466fdae51bbf3dbeabd5dfbf2b02d4da03b e87ffba9df6cd03e0ea1c91821e8f2d3f0af2ca6 fb6abea427f3f4770caed5a4b31deeac606d5391 08671dcf23c663efa9758006af71e3281c119bc8 7cdbf2f37bc64ec765c961af0d6bd301f1cc0826 239d75a028f0eb6141ab5d32b008994367f08edf d6c135ae2ce4a099dfc444dba1e5bd29c7a82e2e 80d40034e9bd2eca48b2833a7846fd097a4e3f60 5741492043ebbc19013baf8c1c162b32b0e37ce5 faf15d38deb1abc2359f6d40315cf089331ba01b f0f1feaf60dea3eae104e5d09a3edb0dcb7f22a3 d9758d39749aa1717d43cf5483027a006f41f09c dccc73a3107c69f8020dce655c2eb10c6d0a6e2f d9758d39749aa1717d43cf5483027a006f41f09c 16e784817e8c4fa4bfcca4e2f985c0c0f9e9219f 418cf50a6e4c5a566d0d962e1aa2036e370ba4d3 7cdbf2f37bc64ec765c961af0d6bd301f1cc0826 --

I can otherwise operate normally on this repository, but not being able to gc is slowly killing the performance...

I'm on Windows 2003 x86. Tried msysGit and cygwin git with identical results. This problem started 2 or 3 days ago, it used to work flawlessly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run a check on your harddisk
2. Clone the repository to a different place and try there

Comment: thanks, it was a disk issue, I ran chkdsk and all is well now.