# Git push halts on "Writing Objects: 100%"

Tags: git

I have set up a linux box with a Git repository (using xinetd).

I have enabled receive-pack for the git daemon to enable pushing to the repository.

Here's my current testing workflow:

1. On git server, run:

> mkdir something
>
> cd something
>
> git init --bare

1. On a client box:

git clone git://server/repo

(msg about cloning an empty repository)

1. Perform some commits to the cloned repository.
2. `git push`

getting this msg:

```
Counting objects: 8, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3) done,
Writing objects: 100% (6/6)
```

This does not finish. I have introduced only a small change, so this should be completed very quickly.

am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Just in case that help, can you try a '`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`' before your `git push`?

Comment: Tried that, still halts.

Comment: worth a try. The other thing to check is permissions: is there any read/write access issue?

Comment: I suppose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887228 wouldn't help in your case? And that you are not using cygwin? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071667). May be a disk issue? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477254). An anti-virus issue? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587125) A router issue? (http://www.mail-archive.com/github@googlegroups.com/msg02184.html). Are you using msysgit on the client side? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520329)

Comment: Yes i am using msysgit. Is there any other "flavor" that can be used? i downloaded it directly from their site. All my cilents will run on Windows (and integrate into Visual Studio). Are there any alternatives?

Comment: on Windows, an alternative (that I wouldn't recommend except for this push operation) is installing Git in a Cygwin session. Other alternative involves JGit-EGit within an Eclipse session. Or Dulwich (http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/)

Comment: i find it hard to believe that the most common (correct me if I'm wrong) git client has this bug for several versions without being fixed. Perhaps this is a far fetched scenario since nobody prefers to use the git protocol for pushing into the server ?

Comment: using the git protocol is indeed rare, but if you read the comments of http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457, you will see it isn't fixed because nobody has managed to really debug that error (or take the time to). That confirms my initial feeling 2 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704565/why-kiln-is-based-on-mercurial-and-not-other-dvcs/1704687#1704687

Comment: Thanks @VonC This was really the issue with my client (msysgit)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is with mgitsys client

Read more here: [MGitsys Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520329)

As a workaround, i am using an older version: *git version 1.7.4.rc1.3197.gbf965*

This one doesn't have this bug in it.

I have placed this specific build in my SkyDrive public folder, link: http://sdrv.ms/MeuWTD

Hopefully it will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: can you give me a link to download this vesrion? i can't find (

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to my SkyDrive with this Git build.

Answer (score 45):

If you are using msysgit - they have just released a version that allows a config option to stop git hanging.

Fix is for https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/101 in release https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.4-preview20140611

You can fix it by setting

```
git config --global sendpack.sideband false
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost 10y later still saved the day.

Comment: I spent hours trying to understand what is wrong. It's a relief