# Git push halts on “Writing Objects: 100%” on Windows 7

Tags: windows, git

When I try to **push** new file into **Git repository**, it doesn't finish, on screen is my workflow:

[image: git push]

I tried:

- TortoiseGit 1.8.1.0 (git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0 (C:\Program
  Files\Git\bin))
- Eclipse EGit 2.1.0
- Command line

without any success. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104182/git-push-halts-on-writing-objects-100) question, but it's quite old (1.5 year), and do not help (I installed git 1.7.4), and was the same. I new in Git, please tell me what am I doing wrong or how to solve it? What do you suggest as a Git client for Windows 7 (32)? (Best if it will support command line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pushing over the Git-protocol is still broken in Git for Windows. So if that's what you're attempting, check if you can push over another protocol instead.

Comment: I changed protocol to http and message showed : git push Unable to create branch path XXXXX/.git/info error: cannot lock existing info/refs fatal: git-http-push failed

Comment: Sounds like you're pushing into a non-bare repo. Is this the case? If so, does it help to use a bare repo?

Comment: What I am doing: git clone http://link -> modify any file -> git commit -a -> git push -> error like above. Strange: Tortoise,Msysgit, EGit don't work, Netbeans embeded git client - works.

Comment: I have bare repo. BTW I found workaround, now I am using Cygwin, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. I pulled and then tried to push to the remote, and it got to 100% writing objects and just stayed there. It didn't request the repo password, nothing.

The solution was related to my .gitconfig file. I had to redo the settings in this file.

I think in mucking around with my git repository (and admittedly learning how git works by breaking it) I had inadvertently removed this file.