# Git push hangs when pushing via ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-push, git-remote

Attempting to push my development branch to my github repo.

```
git push origin develop -v
```

The connection hangs and hangs and hangs and hangs and never times out.  I never receive error messages nor "writing objects" nor any sort of communication.

Connecting via ssh.  Have verified that I can connect via ssh to github meaning my public keys are valid.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/Forkedrepo.git
ssh -T git@github.com
```

What else can I do?  FWIW, I can connect to other sites via ssh and git push.  I also know I CANNOT connect via https over this router.

Using a Windows workstation and git push works with other non-github remote repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy answer after much head scratching.

Don't use Cygwin for github access.  An alternative is to do all your normal terminal functions in Cygwin and then use Windows Command Line for
 `git push origin`

Be sure to have ssh keys added to your account. Here are [steps to add ssh to github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).  Also be sure your ssh keys have a passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of [an answer I just posted elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835811/59532)

I'm wondering if it's the same thing I had...

1. Go into Putty
2. Click on "Default Settings" in the Saved Sessions. Click Load
3. Go to Connection -> SSH -> Bugs
4. Set "Chokes on PuTTY's SSH-2 'winadj' requests" to On (instead of Auto)
5. Go Back to Session in the treeview (top of the list)
6. Click on "Default Settings" in the Saved Sessions box. Click Save.

This (almost verbatim) comes from https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1880