# How can I know how much percentage of git push is complete?

Tags: git, github, git-push

I'm pushing a code of around 200 MB into a repo. It is taking a lot of time. Is there anyway we can display the progress bar, so that I can know how much amount of code is pushed into the repo?

Comment: Pushing 200mb might also indicate that you're using git for something you shouldn't..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "code of around 200 MB"? Do you have a file that's 200 MB in size? Or do the sum of all changes that you've made in the commits that you're pushing actually equal 200 MB?

Comment: @Daenyth, there are perfectly fine cases when you need to push the whole repo - for example when migrating existing repository to a new Git hosted system - Github, Bitbucket, VSTS etc. Such scenarios are quite common.

Comment: @Daenyth, as a developer - yes, less frequent, as a DevOps \ CD specialist I do that more than actual commits :) So, keep open mind!

Comment: The purpose of the question isn't to be close-minded and assume what the OP is trying to do -- he's seeking an answer to a question that's answerable. Best to stay on-topic.

Comment: I don't know why, but git push -u origin master did it...

Answer (score 12):

`git push --progress` will be more precise with Git 2.10 (Q3 2016)

See [commit e376f17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e376f17fd1a1efd4fe425d023610172bcba3fe97) from Jeff King (peff)

> The `index-pack` command has two progress meters:
>
> - one for "receiving objects", and
> - one for "resolving deltas".
>
> You get neither by default, or both with "`-v`".
>
> But for a push through receive-pack, we would want only the "`resolving deltas`" phase, *not* the "`receiving objects`" progress.
> There are two reasons for this:
>
> - One is simply that existing clients are already printing "writing objects" progress at the same time.
>   Arguably "receiving" from the far end is more useful, because it tells you what has actually gotten there, as opposed to what might be stuck in a buffer somewhere between the client and server. But that would require a protocol extension to tell clients not to print their progress. Possible, but
>   complexity for little gain.
> - The second reason is much more important.
>   In a full-duplex connection like git-over-ssh, we can print progress while
>   the pack is incoming, and it will immediately get to the client.
>   But for a half-duplex connection like git-over-http, we should not say anything until we have received the full request.
>   Anything we write is subject to being stuck in a buffer by the webserver.  Worse, we can end up in a deadlock if that buffer fills up.
>
> So our best bet is to **avoid writing anything that isn't a
> small fixed size until we've received the full pack**.

---

Update September 2016: Git 2.10 is there, and you can see an example of this progress meter at the GitHub blog post "[**Git 2.10 has been released**](https://github.com/blog/2242-git-2-10-has-been-released)":

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3477155/18064845/34bb6956-6dff-11e6-8e3e-8a92c0bddaef.gif]

---

Update Git 2.11 (Q4 2016)

Now, an incoming "`git push`" that attempts to push too many bytes can now
be rejected by setting a new configuration variable at the receiving
end.

See [commit c08db5a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c08db5a2d0d5c0cf371168e621d5929005b1abf8), [commit 411481b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/411481be6f27fb1ae8e2263d1e686357226391a3) (24 Aug 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 5ad2186](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ad218673328262839542b841b505c78132857e7) (24 Aug 2016) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit da3b6f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da3b6f06e1224c9b8f5281a812731ef385ac4dc6), 09 Sep 2016)</sup>

> ### `receive-pack`: allow a maximum input size to be specified

> Receive-pack feeds its input to either index-pack or unpack-objects, which will happily accept as many bytes as a sender is willing to provide.
> Let's allow an arbitrary cutoff point where we will stop writing bytes to disk.

[git config doc](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c08db5a2d0d5c0cf371168e621d5929005b1abf8/Documentation/config.txt#L2520-L2524) now includes:

> ### `receive.maxInputSize`
>
> If the size of the incoming pack stream is larger than this limit, then git-receive-pack will error out, instead of accepting the pack file.
> If not set or set to 0, then the size is unlimited.

---

With Git 2.22, the progress is better managed:

See [commit 545dc34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/545dc345ebd00adbd96229e8e46b2e8c0b2f1b37), [commit 9f1fd84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f1fd84e15a8109f02867e369c747a1cbe766ba1) (12 Apr 2019), and [commit d53ba84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d53ba841d4feec0096f5f019ae2d304f1edd226e), [commit 9219d12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9219d12777baf67e001329cad98fa21c55d46b2e) (05 Apr 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 425e51e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/425e51e54d03a510904b9bb10b43a7635f2d085f), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

See [commit 1aed1a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1aed1a5f25ad300dbdc48f0943ca5c3bed952e6a) (19 May 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fa03d9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa03d9c6990aa0f0ca675e89bde1861988d0c517), 30 May 2019)</sup>

> ### `progress`: break too long progress bar lines

> Some of the recently added progress indicators have quite long titles,
> which might be even longer when translated to some languages, and when
> they are shown while operating on bigger repositories, then the
> progress bar grows longer than the default 80 column terminal width.
>
> When the progress bar exceeds the width of the terminal it gets
> line-wrapped, and after that the CR at the end doesn't return to the
> beginning of the progress bar, but to the first column of its last
> line.
> Consequently, the first line of the previously shown progress
> bar is not overwritten by the next, and we end up with a bunch of
> truncated progress bar lines scrolling past:
>
> ```
> $ LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 git commit-graph write
>   Encontrando commits para commit graph entre los objetos empaquetados:   2% (1599
>   Encontrando commits para commit graph entre los objetos empaquetados:   3% (1975
>   Encontrando commits para commit graph entre los objetos empaquetados:   4% (2633
>   Encontrando commits para commit graph entre los objetos empaquetados:   5% (3292
>   [...]
> ```
>
> Prevent this by breaking progress bars after the title once they
> exceed the width of the terminal, so the counter and optional
> percentage and throughput, i.e. all changing parts, are on the last
> line.
> Subsequent updates will from then on only refresh the changing
> parts, but not the title, and it will look like this:
>
> ```
> $ LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 ~/src/git/git commit-graph write
>   Encontrando commits para commit graph entre los objetos empaquetados:
>   100% (6584502/6584502), listo.
>   Calculando números de generación de commit graph: 100% (824705/824705), listo.
>   Escribiendo commit graph en 4 pasos: 100% (3298820/3298820), listo.
> ```

---

Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) fixes the progress display of a rebase:

See [commit 5b12e31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b12e3123b7b70e3875404a4ffe571ca079364fe), [commit cd1096b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd1096b2820d64d5fcb5da20613d5af290e42929), [commit 077b979](https://github.com/git/git/commit/077b9798919ac2aa63600a1547f55f89b62b3b02), [commit c9749b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9749b369da14cbac6201b1730586abf1f3974f6) (24 Jun 2019), and [commit d7d9088](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7d90885e0aeb50eb4acc221ee43301b2a43aa3e) (27 Jun 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6624e07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6624e07b36c97e04ba68c8310a70bc69433e187e), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `rebase`: fix garbled progress display with '`-x`'

> When running a command with the '`exec`' instruction during an interactive rebase session, or for a range of commits using '`git rebase -x`', the output can be a bit garbled when the name of the command is short enough:
>
> ```
>  $ git rebase -x true HEAD~5
>  Executing: true
>  Executing: true
>  Executing: true
>  Executing: true
>  Executing: true)
>  Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
> ```
>
> Note the '`)`' at the end of the last line.
> It gets more garbled as the range of commits increases:
>
> ```
>  $ git rebase -x true HEAD~50
>  Executing: true)
>  [ repeated 3 more times ]
>  Executing: true0)
>  [ repeated 44 more times ]
>  Executing: true00)
>  Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
> ```
>
> Those extra numbers and '`)`' are remnants of the previously displayed "`Rebasing (N/M)`" progress lines that are usually completely overwritten by the "`Executing: <cmd>`" lines, unless '`cmd`' is short and the "`N/M`" part is long.
>
> Make sure that the previously displayed "`Rebasing (N/M)`" line is cleared by using the `term_clear_line()` helper function added in the previous patch.
> Do so only when not being '`--verbose`', because in that case these "`Rebasing (N/M)`" lines are not printed as progress (i.e. as lines with '`\r`' at the end), but as "regular" output (with '`\n`' at the end).
>
> A couple of other rebase commands print similar messages, e.g. "`Stopped at <abbrev-oid>... <subject>`" for the '`edit`' or '`break`' commands, or the "`Successfully rebased and updated <full-ref>.`" at the very end.
>
> These are so long that they practically always overwrite that "`Rebasing (N/M)`" progress line, but let's be prudent, and clear the last line before printing these, too.
>
> In '`t3420-rebase-autostash.sh`', two helper functions prepare the
> expected output of four tests that check the full output of '`git rebase`' and thus are affected by this change, so adjust their expectations to account for the new line clearing.
>
> Note that this patch doesn't completely eliminate the possibility of
> similar garbled outputs, e.g. some error messages from rebase or the
> "`Auto-merging <file>`" message from within the depths of the merge
> machinery might not be long enough to completely cover the last
> "`Rebasing (N/M)`" line.
>
> This patch doesn't do anything about them, because dealing with them individually would result in way too much churn, while having a catch-all `term_clear_line()` call in the common code path of `pick_commits()` would hide the "`Rebasing (N/M)`" line way too soon, and it would either flicker or be invisible.

---

However, Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) includes a regression fix for progress output

See [commit 2bb74b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2bb74b53a49f92d433057f4d560b33f1fe2f770a), [commit bbf4756](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bbf47568ad7e91ab0962b314c054a2da03232c72) (16 Sep 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ef93bfb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef93bfbd45c660d688d41f319485a9cf6e9cba6f), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### Test the progress display

> '`progress.c`' has seen a few fixes recently ([commit 545dc34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/545dc345ebd00adbd96229e8e46b2e8c0b2f1b37) and [commit 9f1fd84](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f1fd84e15a8109f02867e369c747a1cbe766ba1), both v2.22.0-rc0), and, unfortunately,
> some of those fixes required further fixes ([commit 1aed1a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1aed1a5f25ad300dbdc48f0943ca5c3bed952e6a)).
>
> The progress display is, however, critically dependent on timing, because it's only updated once every second or, if the total is known in advance, every 1%, and there is the throughput rate as well.  These
> make the progress display far too undeterministic for testing as-is.

Hence:

> ### `progress`: avoid empty line when breaking the progress line

> Since [commit 545dc34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/545dc345ebd00adbd96229e8e46b2e8c0b2f1b37) (`progress`: break too long progress bar lines,
> 2019-04-12, Git v2.22.0-rc0) when splitting a too long progress line, sometimes it
> looks as if a superfluous empty line were added between the title line and the counters.
>
> To make sure that the previously displayed progress line is completely covered up when writing the new, shorter title line, we calculate how many characters need to be overwritten with spaces.
> Alas, this calculation doesn't account for the newline character at the end of
> the new title line, and resulted in printing one more space than strictly necessary.
> This extra space character doesn't matter, if the length of the previous progress line was shorter than the width of the terminal.
> However, if the previous line matched the terminal width, then this extra space made the new line longer, effectively adding that empty line after the title line.
>
> Fix this off-by-one to avoid that spurious empty line.

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), one kind of progress messages were always given during commit-graph generation, instead of following the "**if it takes more than two seconds, show progress**" pattern, which has been corrected.

See [commit ecc0869](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecc0869080701b5e252f74ed7b3d0156a5ec6112), [commit 44a4693](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44a4693bfcec1876b29cdaec3625819d80ea1280) (25 Nov 2019) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 41dac79](https://github.com/git/git/commit/41dac79c2f49f9ea1c808f0f208bde9aa4ed91cb), 10 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`commit-graph`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecc0869080701b5e252f74ed7b3d0156a5ec6112): use `start_delayed_progress()`
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: ryenus</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When writing a commit-graph, we show progress along several commit walks. When we use `start_delayed_progress()`, the progress line will only appear if that step takes a decent amount of time.
>
> However, one place was missed: computing generation numbers. This is normally a very fast operation as all commits have been parsed in a previous step. But, this is showing up for all users no matter how few commits are being added.
>
> The tests that check for the progress output have already been updated to use `GIT_PROGRESS_DELAY=0` to force the expected output.

That new environment variable comes from:

> ### [`progress`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44a4693bfcec1876b29cdaec3625819d80ea1280): create `GIT_PROGRESS_DELAY`
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The `start_delayed_progress()` method is a **preferred way to show optional progress to users as it ignores steps that take less than two seconds**.
> However, this makes testing unreliable as tests expect to be very fast.
>
> In addition, users may want to decrease or increase this time interval depending on their preferences for terminal noise.
>
> Create the `GIT_PROGRESS_DELAY` environment variable to control the delay set during `start_delayed_progress()`.
> Set the value in some tests to guarantee their output remains consistent.

The [`git` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/44a4693bfcec1876b29cdaec3625819d80ea1280/Documentation/git.txt#L547-L549) now includes:

> ### `GIT_PROGRESS_DELAY`:
>
> A number controlling how many seconds to delay before showing optional progress indicators.
> Defaults to 2.

---

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), commit-graph can show progress of finding reachable commits.

See [commit 2f00c35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f00c355cb79ee86bddc9f2fef91ac380a6023fc), [commit 1f1304d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f1304d4976f54b1afa5d71b55e41c6c1b5f9ac1), [commit 0ec2d0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ec2d0ff07f125b7dcf0fde2b508fa8d6d35e939), [commit 5b6653e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b6653e523cd2a0357924caef339adfeab12903b), [commit 630cd51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/630cd5194e6fcf928290a5c0f85e4094559197c8), [commit d335ce8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d335ce8f24e335ffda911f01a9569f7132e64cdb) (13 May 2020), [commit fa8953c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa8953cb401d2c73c280eb6c70e7a7918dbe8bfb) (18 May 2020), and [commit 1fe1084](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fe10844cad39db18de18412c928a0e69b0067ae) (05 May 2020) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc57a9b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc57a9be5ee2f9c719965a9e6c7a2ed97af180a1), 09 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`commit-graph.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d335ce8f24e335ffda911f01a9569f7132e64cdb): show progress of finding reachable commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When '[`git commit-graph write --reachable`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-graph) ' is invoked, the commit-graph machinery calls '`for_each_ref()`' to discover the set of reachable commits.
>
> Right now the '`add_ref_to_set`' callback is not doing anything other than adding an OID to the set of known-reachable OIDs. In a subsequent commit, '`add_ref_to_set`' will presumptively peel references. This operation should be fast for repositories with an up-to-date '`$GIT_DIR/packed-refs`', but may be slow in the general case.
>
> So that it doesn't appear that '[`git commit-graph write`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-graph)' is idling with '`--reachable`' in the slow case, add a progress meter to provide some output in the meantime.
>
> In general, we don't expect a progress meter to appear at all, since peeling references with a 'packed-refs' file is quick.
> If it's slow and we do show a progress meter, the subsequent '`fill_oids_from_commits()`' will be fast, since all of the calls to '`lookup_commit_reference_gently()`' will be no-ops.
>
> Both progress meters are delayed, so it is unlikely that more than one will appear. In either case, this intermediate state will go away in a handful of patches, at which point there will be at most one progress meter.

---

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), the code to produce progress output from "git commit-graph --write" had a few breakages, which have been fixed in the same 2.28 release.

See [commit 150cd3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/150cd3b61d55bedd275e0ed36a6f674dcd34ae25), [commit 6f9d5f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f9d5f2fda1f94cf1539d3e0529c2b2e7ee7eebb) (09 Jul 2020) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 12f5eb9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12f5eb9f082d7f4cb083a11aa59ac8bbd5e1589a), 15 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`commit-graph`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f9d5f2fda1f94cf1539d3e0529c2b2e7ee7eebb): fix progress of reachable commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>

> To display a progress line while iterating over all refs, [d335ce8f24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d335ce8f24e335ffda911f01a9569f7132e64cdb) ("`commit-graph.c`: show progress of finding reachable commits", 2020-05-13, Git v2.28.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc57a9be5ee2f9c719965a9e6c7a2ed97af180a1) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0313f36c6ebecb3bffe6f15cf25a4883100f0214)) should have added a pair of `start_delayed_progress()` and `stop_progress()` calls around a `for_each_ref()` invocation.
>
> Alas, the `stop_progress()` call ended up at the wrong place, after `write_commit_graph()`, which does all the commit-graph computation and writing, and has several progress lines of its own.
>
> Consequently, that new
>
> ```
> Collecting referenced commits: 123
> ```
>
> progress line is overwritten by the first progress line shown by `write_commit_graph()`, and its final "done" line is shown last, after everything is finished:
>
> ```
> Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 344786, done.
> Computing commit changed paths Bloom filters: 100% (344786/344786), done.
> Collecting referenced commits: 154, done.
> ```
>
> Move that `stop_progress()` call to the right place.
>
> While at it, drop the unnecessary 'if (data.progress)' condition protecting the `stop_progress()` call, because that function is prepared to handle a `NULL` progress struct.

See more at [commit 862aead](https://github.com/git/git/commit/862aead24eaf797860fb503561a1f86adf557abb) (10 Jul 2020) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d1ae8ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1ae8ba0963378f6613bfd683a969a94ca01b344), 15 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`commit-graph`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/862aead24eaf797860fb503561a1f86adf557abb): fix "Collecting commits from input" progress line
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

Answer (score 7):

It's not a progress "bar", but `git push` already reports progress by default when it's run from a terminal. From the [official Linux kernel git documentation for `git push`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> ```
> --progress
> ```
>
> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default when it is attached to a terminal, unless `-q` is specified. This flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not directed to a terminal.

The fact that you're trying to push 200 MB at once suggests that you might be doing something sub-optimally with git.