# attempting to push updates to bitbuckets hangs

Tags: github, bitbucket

I am attempting to push updates to git using bitbucket and it hangs at this point

```
Total 349 (delta 84), reused 1 (delta 0)
```

EDITTED
here is the command I run

```
git add .
git commit --m "infor..."
git push
```

This is the complete thing of what I get>>>>

```
Counting objects: 398, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (382/382), done.
Writing objects: 100% (398/398), 176.64 MiB | 48.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 398 (delta 121), reused 1 (delta 0)
```

Please what could be wrong

Comment: Can you provide any other details?

Comment: I have added more info to include the command I run

Comment: I meant about the response.

Comment: check my edits again..... I have added the complete response

Comment: it just hangs on the last line

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is not a case of very long upload, [as in this instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16084403/6309).

For that, as I described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788417/6309), try (with Git 2.10 or more recent) the [`--progress` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---progress):

```
 git push --progress
```