# Track status of GitHub push?

Tags: github

I'm attempting to push a commit ('master') to a remote ('origin/master').  The commit contains changes to 5 python scripts, each under 1000 lines of code.  When I push, it goes very slowly as if it were pushing a very large file, then eventually times out when the status bar is at about 90%.

Is there a way to check what information is getting pushed that's so cumbersome, or what's causing it to time out?

EDIT: When I run git diff, it only shows 5 python scripts as being modified.  But when I push, it says "Compressing objects: (170/170)".  There are some very large files in my local repo but they are listed in the .gitignore.

Comment: Did you committed and then removed these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, try a [`git push --progress`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---progress), which is [more precise since Git 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788417/6309).

For even more details:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push --progress
```

Then, make sure your large files listed in the .gitignore are not yet in the index:

```
git rm --cached -- alargeFile
```