# git-gui--askpass: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I ran the following command in terminal:
git config --global core.askpass "git-gui--askpass"

Now, I get this error message whenever I attempt to push to github:
"error: cannot run git-gui--askpass: No such file or directory"
It shows up twice, once prior to the email prompt, then another prior to the password prompt.

I can successfully push, but the error message still shows up.
How do I stop this error from showing up?

Thank you in advance for reading/helping :)

(Note: I ran the command only after several failed attempts to push a **new** rails project to github; the push kept hanging on me and I got desperate. So I searched around stackoverflow and someone here suggested running that command. I didn't know what it was, I just ran it because I thought it would work; it still doesn't work for pushing the new project; pushing only works for the projects I currently have on github, but the error still shows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue.

(the long explanation below is only for noobs like me)

It turns out, when running this command => "git config --global core.askpass git-gui--askpass", we end up creating a global setting (explains the --global part), and this is actually written into .gitconfig, which is an actual file found in your home directory (I'm using ubuntu in my virtual machine). the file itself is hidden, so hit CRTL + h to see it. open it, and if you ran the command above like me, you'll likely see this in .gitconfig:

[core]

```
    askpass = git-gui--askpass
```

the file is editable as you might expect. delete that line and the "error" i mentioned in my original post will not appear in the terminal anymore when you attempt a push to github.

Answer (score 12):

You may also run...

```
git config --global --unset-all core.askpass
```

..., which should work.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this may be helpful for you :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/+bug/601595