# Terminal is stuck after git push

Tags: android, git

After I've pushed my code the terminal is stuck and only a blank line is displayed. It doesn't show any error. When I try to close terminal it shows processes are running. I don't know what happens. This is the third time I've pushed my code. It just worked at previews times. Everything has been set at first time push.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running git in verbose mode. run `git push -v` to have an idea of what's happening in your terminal.

Comment: it shows  pushing  to https:// ...  at the next lane.  and stuck there.  the repo address is right

Answer (score 0):

Check the following possible options:

- `$ git remote show origin`

  If it shows the URL as `git://`, try pushing to git using `http://`. Might be the case that the router is blocking the port.
- Check your SSH config (`~/.ssh/config`)
- See if your origin is directed to the correct URL (`git remote -v`) and that you have write access. Command: `git gc`
- Might be an issue with the Repo Hosting provider.
- Try this:

  `git config --global core.askpass "git-gui--askpass"`

  The prompt may ask for login credentials. If there is any error, check
  [git-gui--askpass: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294980/git-gui-askpass-no-such-file-or-directory).

Comment: thank you for helping. it push to right url I just checked. but still stuck there