# Git clone clone hangs for long time without error in GIT BASH

Tags: git, git-bash, ado

I am trying to clone ADO repo locally but when i am trying to clone repo using git bash
it is not showing any error but hangs forever.

tried git config --global credential.provider generic given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119535/git-clone-hangs-on-cloning-into-using-gitbash)
but it is not working

tried to execute --verbose flag as well but not showing any output.

ideally it should give popup for GIT Credentials Manager but it is not happening.

Comment: Try `strace git clone` and it could give a clue.

Comment: @ElpieKay it is giving logs like this 


` 
--- Process 21916, exception c0000005 at 000000021006306c 
--- Process 21916, exception c0000005 at 000000021006306c
--- Process 21916, exception c0000005 at 000000021006306c
--- Process 21916 exited with status 0xc0000005
--- Process 11872 thread 21868 exited with status 0x80
`
any clue ?

Comment: below it giving ,

cannot spawn C:/Program Files/Git/usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass: No such file or directory

fatal: could not read Password for "URL"

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294980/git-gui-askpass-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help