# Git bash frozen after git push

Tags: git, push, freeze

I'm new to git and I was learning to use git push a changed file to a repository in my github. But when I use `git push origin master` nothing comes up and it break until I use cntrl + c. I saw many faced the same issue but none of the solutions worked for me. Something that I realized, sometimes as I break the session a window pops up and ask for user name passwords for Github, but when I enter it say broken pipe. I assue it should pop up before I break the session using cntrl+ c but not luck yet. Any ideas?
P.S : I have cloned a repository and and `git remote -v` returns `origin  https://github.com/username/reponame (fetch) origin  https://github.com/username/reponame (push)`

Comment: Can you do a curl in that git-bash to your repo?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what curl does

Comment: "*I saw many faced the same issue but none of the solutions worked for me.*" What have you tried? Upgrade? Downgrade? Change the protocol to SSH?

Comment: I uninstall, upgrade, change my internet connection, all methods in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906161/git-push-hangs-when-pushing-to-github

Comment: `curl https://github.com/username/reponame` and validate if you're able to connect to that repo at all via git-bash. Are you in a cooperate environment?