# Git remote pull do not proceed

Tags: git, github

It is time for me to use git. I have downloaded the git, made remote repo https://github.com/vVicoo/pokemon-scrap (with README and LICENSE files there), commit changes on my local repository where my project lies. I tried to push my 1-file script via

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/vVicoo/pokemon-scrap.git
git branch -m master main
git push origin main
```

The effect is that the git bash console do not proceed, it is like the push command takes forever.

Any ideas what is the cause of such issue? Did I create remote repo improperly? There is something wrong with push itself?

Actually this is rather simple task, for now it is only one file script that has to be pushed.

[image: Screenshot that shows list of commands I made]

Comment: I did add the files, make a commit and push still freezes :(

Comment: I added the screenshot that shows my console status

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git push hangs when pushing to Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906161/git-push-hangs-when-pushing-to-github)

Comment: can you show us your `git status` and `git log main..origin/main` just in case?

Comment: @Alex028502 here are records from git status:
$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean.

About this log main:
$ git log main..--origin/main
fatal: ambiguous argument 'main..--origin/main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: @deepakchethan I tried the command "git config --global core.askpass "git-gui--askpass"" but it didn't help

Comment: can you try `git fetch` and then do that again?  I don't think you have downloaded the stuff you put there with the github interface

Comment: Since your repo is public, you should be able to fetch without authentication