# A way to debug what's happening in git push/pull commands?

Tags: git, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm facing an issue with Github, whereby all local commands work (AKA, merge, rebase checkout, etc) but all commands that involve the origin repo hangs (AKA pull, push)

The problem is similar to [the issue raised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906161/git-push-hangs-when-pushing-to-github).

The environment im using is windows WSL2, ubuntu 20.04.3.

With that being said, is there a way for me to get more information on what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem you're describing when working on a group project for school with some classmates. It turns out that ssh access was blocked on the guest wifi networks at that location, which is what my team mate was connected to. Even though he had internet access, he couldn't push or pull from github because ssh was blocked.

This sounds a lot like a that, so I'm providing this answer.

First, check if you can access github via SSH at all:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

If you can, it might be a separate issue, but if you can't, you're on a network that's blocking ssh.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting a public key denied error is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Is the public key you uploaded to git the one you currently have on your machine?