# Git freeze up during writing

Tags: git, push, freeze

My friend has created a local git repository to work in. We are 3 on the project. At the beginning of the project, I was able to push, pull etc... But now, it's impossible for me to push my work. I can clone, pull, but when I push it always says:

```
Writing object: 100% (4/4)
```

and then freezes... This is the original clone of the repository, I have only added a space in a file.

I tried with cmd, PowerShell, the git GUI and git bash, nothing worked, rebooted my system, but still it is not working from the last 1 or 2 weeks...

I have also tried git clean -f -n, and many other things found on the internet...

I am desperate, it's impossible for me to work correctly in my team...

Thanks a lot...

Comment: You can have a look to this answer. [The problem seems to be same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24461847)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot ! A haven't see this topic, it seems to work.. wow, thanks a lot ! :D